# Setting PHP $_ENV variables in Elastic Beanstalk docker container

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have an Docker container running nginx and php-fpm using supervisord.
I am trying to use .ebextensions/*.config to set up environment variables.

Although the variables are set up in the container (e.g `# echo $VAR` prints the expected value), I can't find an easy way to make them available to PHP. IMHO I could only write a bash script to read and copy the vars to `www.conf` or to nginx host config as fcgi_param. But then this script will need to know which variables to copy... .

I am wondering if anyone found an easier way to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote bash script which will copy env vars starting with a list of prefixes to the fpm's www.conf file and baked it into my image's start.sh script.

This still won't put variables in $_ENV :( but will add them to $_SERVER and are available via `getenv()`.

Script is here: [adrian7/php-transfer-vars.sh](https://gist.github.com/adrian7/96940b05ce8526da9ae3)

Comment: what if the variable's value was updated via the UI or API? a bad practice.

Comment: FYI the script runs inside the container(s) on startup. We've used it for over an year and did not had any issues yet.

Answer (score -1):

There are two ways to do this with any reliability. For all of the web side stuff set the environment variables in an .htaccess file. You could do this for your database connection information, for example:

```
# environment variables
SetEnv DBL "mysql:dbname=mydatabase;host=localhost;port=3306"
SetEnv DB_USER "root"
SetEnv DB_PASS "fruitygoodness"
```

Place the .htaccess file in the web root in your container. When you need the environment variables you can retrieve them with PHP's [`getenv()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getenv.php).

```
define('DBL', getenv('DBL'));
define('USER', getenv('DB_USER'));
define('PASS', getenv('DB_PASS'));
```

For the PHP-CLI inside the container you would specify the environment variables in the Docker `run` command by specifying the option `-e` prior to each variable. Here is an example:

```
sudo docker run --name mysite -e "DBL=mysql:dbname=mydatabase;host=localhost;port=3306" -e "DB_USER=root" -e "DB_PASS=fruitgoodness" -p 80:80 -p 443:443 -P -d  repo/mysite
```

Doing this makes the environment variables available to the container *but not to the web server running in the container*.